# What kind of a JQuery selector can I use to select a link by data attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML on my page:

```
<a data-href="/C003Q/History"><span>History</span></a>
```

Is there a JQuery selector that will allow me to send a click event to the link?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "Send a click event to the link"

Comment: Do you mean bind a click event listener to the a tag?

Comment: Do you want to trigger te click event or send a handler for it?

Comment: $('#abc').click(); But for some selector that will get the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `attribute` selector,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kWrhu/1/)**

```
$('a[data-href="/C003Q/History"]').click(function(){        
   alert("clicked");
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this method if you want to trigger the click event:

```
$('a[data-href="/C003Q/History"]').click();
```

Or use the following code if you want to pass a click handler to the link:

```
$('a[data-href="/C003Q/History"]').click(function(){
    console.log("click");
    //And do your logic here
});
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following to know when someone click on the link.

```
$('a[data-href="/C003Q/History"]').click(function() {
   alert('click !');
});
```

If you want to "simultate" a click on the link, use the following :

```
$('a[data-href="/C003Q/History"]').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('a[data-href="/C003Q/History"]')
```

:)